# Upload asset in Google Earth Engine with Python?

Tags: python, command-line, google-earth-engine

I want upload an asset to Earth Engine with Python and I don't want use Google Cloud Storage.

Is there a way to upload a particular file (from my computer) directly to the Google Earth Engine using the command line (or using a Python script)?

Comment: what did you do and how did it fail?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i use geemap module and bypass uploading file on googleEarthEngine

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only upload from Google Cloud Storage via python. The only way to upload directly from your computer is via the playground.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upload some data from the Python API and get some asset too.
Check this:
https://spatialthoughts.com/2022/02/24/gee-asset-management/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).